# WSO2 Thrift Asynchronous

Tags: wso2

WSO2 folks,

I heard there's a Data Bridge in WSO2 that can support thrift asynchronous RPC, I looked throught the documents but couldn't find it anywhere. Can somebody point me to such a document on how to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 Products such as CEP and DAS use data bridge and data agent with thrift protocol. You can have WSO2Event Receiver [1] with thrift protocol to collect data and WSO2Event Publisher [2] to publish via thrift. Read Publishing Data to CEP documentation for more details such as thrift configurations [3].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/WSO2Event+Event+Receiver

[2]https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/WSO2Event+Event+Publisher

[3] https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=47517008